# How do I view my website traffic for a GAE product?

Tags: google-app-engine, vs-web-site-project, web-traffic

I recently moved my website from being hosted with cPanel to being hosted on the Google App Engine. Everything has been a much better experience with the GAE but I can't seem to figure out how to view the traffic to my website. With cPanel there were a few apps on the dashboard I could use that would show me the views and the IP addresses and dates associated with each view. With GAE I only see a summary and API requests graphs, which don't really tell me the information I need (or I don't know how to read them properly, that's also a possibility). Is there any way to view your website traffic through the GAE dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: isn't that kind of an external solution though? I was hoping there was something inside of Google Cloud Services that could give me information as an administrator as to my sites traffic.

Comment: Actually I just checked and it is exactly what I needed, thank you!